# Plotting a line graph along with Bar graph in d3js. Issue with Date

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm learning d3js using various examples found online.

I've been trying to plot a chart with dual Y axis and an X-axis. The Y axis on the left side would plot a **bar** chart against the X-axis and the Y-axis on the right side would plot a **line** chart against X-axis. The Bar graph plots as exactly as required but the line graph does not. The X-axis is date (2015-10-15 04:10).  Following [this](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3883245) example.

The code I wrote

```
var margin = {top: 50, right: 50, bottom: 100, left: 50},
width = 900 - margin.left - margin.right,
height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S").parse;

var x = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, width], .05);

var yTxnVol = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);
var yResTime = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom")

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(yTxnVol)
    .orient("left")

var yAxis2 = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(yResTime)
    .orient("right")
    .ticks(10);
var svg = d3.selectAll("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.csv("../res/data.csv", function(error, data) {

   data.forEach(function(d) {
       d.AVRG_RESP_TIME = +d.AVRG_RESP_TIME;
       d.TXN_VOL = +d.TXN_VOL;
  });

  x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.TYM; }));
  yTxnVol.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.TXN_VOL+50; })]);
  yResTime.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.AVRG_RESP_TIME+50; })]);

  var minDate = d3.min(data, function(d){return d.TYM});
  var maxDate = d3.max(data, function(d){ return d.TYM});
  var xScale = d3.time.scale().range([0,width]);//.domain([minDate, maxDate]);
  xScale.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return new Date(d.TYM); }));

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis)
    .selectAll("text")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .attr("dx", "-.8em")
      .attr("dy", "-.55em")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)" );

   svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)

   svg.append("g")
      .attr("class","y axis")
      .attr("transform","translate("+width+ ", 0)")
      .call(yAxis2)

   svg.selectAll("bar")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("class", "yhover")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.TYM); })
      .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
      .attr("y", function(d) { return yTxnVol(d.TXN_VOL); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - yTxnVol(d.TXN_VOL); })

   var line = d3.svg.line()
      .x(function(d) { return xScale(new Date(d.TYM));})
      .y(function(d) { return d.AVRG_RESP_TIME; });

   svg.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", line);   
});
```

The Output[image] Trying to make this to a meaningful line graph. Got NaN error while formatting the dates.
Could someone help me to make this a proper line graph ?

The csv data sample

TYM, AVRG_RESP_TIME, TXN_VOL

2015-10-15 04:00:00, 12, 170

2015-10-15 04:10:00, 18, 220

2015-10-15 04:20:00, 28, 251

2015-10-15 05:00:00, 19, 100

Comment: You question really boils down to, how do I convert my `AVRG_RESP_TIME` to a meaning full number?  What does `04:10:238.00` represent?  Minutes:seconds:milliseconds?  Hours:Minutes:seconds?  Just doing `+'04:10:238.00'` isn't going to convert a timespan to a number.

Comment: Sorry about the data sample. The TYM data is 2015-10-15 04:00:00 (04 hours, 00 minutes, 00 seconds). I've been trying to convert the date to a number. Not getting the proper result though.

Answer (score 2):

First, fix your csv file.  It is improperly formatted and should not have spaces after the comma.

Second, You are trying to mix an ordinal scale and a time scale for you xAxis.  This isn't going to work.  For your use case, just stick with time.

Here's a reworking of your code with explanatory comments:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="d3@3.5.3" data-semver="3.5.3" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.3/d3.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    var margin = {
        top: 50,
        right: 50,
        bottom: 100,
        left: 50
      },
      width = 900 - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
      
    var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").parse;

    // x scale should be time and only time
    var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
    var yTxnVol = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);
    var yResTime = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(x)
      .orient("bottom")

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(yTxnVol)
      .orient("left")

    var yAxis2 = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(yResTime)
      .orient("right")
      .ticks(10);
      
    var svg = d3.selectAll("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    //d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {
      
      var data = [{"TYM":"2015-10-15 04:00:00","AVRG_RESP_TIME":"12","TXN_VOL":"170"},{"TYM":"2015-10-15 04:10:00","AVRG_RESP_TIME":"18","TXN_VOL":"220"},{"TYM":"2015-10-15 04:20:00","AVRG_RESP_TIME":"28","TXN_VOL":"251"},{"TYM":"2015-10-15 05:00:00","AVRG_RESP_TIME":"19","TXN_VOL":"100"}];

      // just make TYM a date and keep it as a date
      data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.TYM = parseDate(d.TYM);
        d.AVRG_RESP_TIME = +d.AVRG_RESP_TIME;
        d.TXN_VOL = +d.TXN_VOL;
      });
      
      // get our min and max date in milliseconds
      // set a padding around our domain of 15%
      var minDate = d3.min(data, function(d){
        return d.TYM;
      }).getTime();
      var maxDate = d3.max(data, function(d){
        return d.TYM;
      }).getTime();
      var padDate = (maxDate - minDate) * .15;
      x.domain([new Date(minDate - padDate), new Date(maxDate + padDate)]);
      
      yTxnVol.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
        return d.TXN_VOL + 50;
      })]);
      
      yResTime.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
        return d.AVRG_RESP_TIME + 50;
      })]);
      
      // set an intelligent bar width
      var barWidth = (width / x.ticks().length) - 20;
      
      svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis)
        .selectAll("text")
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .attr("dx", "-.8em")
        .attr("dy", "-.55em")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)");

      svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis)

      svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + width + ", 0)")
        .call(yAxis2)

      svg.selectAll("bar")
        .data(data)
        .enter().append("rect")
        .attr("class", "yhover")
        .attr("x", function(d) {
          // center bar on time
          return x(d.TYM) - (barWidth / 2);
        })
        .attr("width", barWidth) 
        .attr("y", function(d) {
          return yTxnVol(d.TXN_VOL);
        })
        .attr("height", function(d) {
          return height - yTxnVol(d.TXN_VOL);
        })
        .style("fill","orange");

      var line = d3.svg.line()
        .x(function(d) {
          return x(d.TYM);
        })
        .y(function(d) {
          return d.AVRG_RESP_TIME;
        });

      svg.append("path")
        .datum(data)
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", line)
        .style("fill","none")
        .style("stroke","steelblue")
        .style("stoke-width","3px");
   // });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer.
I was wondering if it was possible to have separate bars for individual time stamps (TYM) and gap between them. I am able to achieve it using ordinal scale but not time scale.

Comment: The issue with the line graph filling with black was due to improper css.
 For the dates I formatted it to (%Y-%m-%d %H:%M) format and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with the line graph filling with black was due to improper css. The new css property.

```
.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: darkgreen;
  stroke-width: 2.5px;
}
```

For the dates I formatted it to (%Y-%m-%d %H:%M) format and it worked.